# How to run python code from ace editor

Tags: html, ace-editor

I am working on a project that uses [ace editor](http://ace.c9.io).

I want to take the user's inputted python code and run the code and show the user the output. I know that this can be done for javascript but can it be done for python.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: [This article](https://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/pypy-js-first-steps/) might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

To do that you have to get server side script support(PHP,ASP,JSP.. )

I can give you example from PHP, You have to send  ace editor input to server and get executed output back to the output window, this question is broad, I gave you server side part !

```
<?php
   $myfile = fopen("main.py", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = "#print (\"Hello World!\")";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
    $output = `python main.py`;
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

**Further reading [DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)**
N.B :pyhton should be installed on your server and you should have permissions

> The backtick operator is disabled when safe mode is enabled or shell_exec() is disabled.

hope this will be helpful !